# Projection of the Lebesgue measure

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $\pi: \mathbb R^2 \rightarrow \mathbb R$ be defined by $\pi (x, y) = x.$

Let $\mu^* : \mathcal P (\mathbb R^2) \rightarrow [0, \infty]$ be defined by: $\mu^* (A) = \lambda_1^* (\pi (A))$ where $\lambda^*(A) = $ inf$\{ \sum vol(R_i): \{R_i\} \in C_A \}$ and $C_A$ the family of all sequences $\{R_i\}$ of bounded and open intervals.

Why is in this case $\mu^*$ an outer measure?

Comment: What book is this problem from? It looks cool.

Comment: Just check that the definition is satisfied.